# Convert Actionscript date string

Tags: c#, .net, flash

I'd like to convert a bunch of date strings like the following Mon Aug 7 15:32:52 GMT+0900 2007
to
C# datetime objects.

Is there anything built in to the .net framework to do this or will I have to parse the string into date parts?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
 DateTime.Parse(datestring);
```

or

```
DateTime.TryParse(string, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles, out DateTime)
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) method. You can use the [DateTimeFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx) class as IFormatProvider. There you could specify the format of the date you want to parse.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure what "date strings like the following" means since seems you forgot to provide a example. But maybe if you try this.

```
string date = DateTime.Today.ToString("ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss G'M'Tzzz yyyy", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-EN"));
date = date.Remove(date.LastIndexOf(':'), 1);
// Do whatever you want with the date string
// Output looks like Wed Sep 9 00:00:00 GMT+0200 2009
```

Comment: `Mon Aug 7 15:32:52 GMT+0900 2007` is in there :)

Comment: he placed a "to" before the actual date string which made me think he wanted to convert "to" that format. :\

Comment: I've cleaned it up. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a simple RFC formatted date, so a straight DateTime.Parse as Ikke said will work and you shouldn't have to provide the format. You can pass a `DateTime` object as the second argument in the [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx) method to see whether it fails or not, as it returns a boolean.